# Caling function that uses array as parameter

Tags: c++

I'm having some difficulty with my syntax. The purpose of the below program is to print an array of 20 random numbers, find the max of the array and then print the array and the max. I've got the sections to initialize and create the array without any problem, but my issue is with the find_max function. In the main function, I'm trying to work out the syntax to call my find_max function there so I can print the results. If anyone can help to fix my syntax, I'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using
namespace std;

void
init_array(int array[], int size, int range)
{
   for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
      array[index] = rand() % range;
}

void print_array(int array[], int size)
{
   for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
      cout << array[index] << " ";
   cout << endl;
}

int find_max (int array[], int size)
{
   int max = array[0];
   for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
   {
      if (array[index] > max)
         max = array[index];
   }
   return max;
}


int main()
{
   // Declare array of integers
    const int size = 20;
    int array[size] = {0};
    int max = find_max(array,size);


   // Initialize and print array
   init_array(array, size, 100);
   print_array(array, size);
   cout << "The max is:" << max << endl;



   return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to find max **before** the array is initialized. That is not what you want. The following works:

```
   const int DATA_SIZE = 20;
   int data[DATA_SIZE] = {0};

   // Initialize and print array
   init_array(data, DATA_SIZE, 100);
   print_array(data, DATA_SIZE);

   // Find maximum value
   int max = find_max(data, DATA_SIZE);

   cout << "max = " << max << endl;

   return 0;
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your call of `find_max` needs to use your declared variables and that after you call `init_array`. Otherwise your array is empty.

The call to `find_max` should look like this:

```
int max = find_max(data, DATA_SIZE);
```

Comment: That makes sense and by implementing those changes, the function doesn't work. Don't I need to use the same declared variables from my find_max function. I made those changes you suggested and now the program works, but my function doesn't work now. It merely prints the max being equal to zero.

Comment: Don't know how the code looks after changes, but maybe try to seed the rand at the beginning of the main: `srand(time(NULL));`.

Comment: @Lumberjacked216: You're asking about the code that you have just written to print the max, and that you have not yet presented. We are not telepaths. We cannot see that code.

Comment: Maybe my issue is with the function. I have a function that finds the maximum of the array and then from that, returns a single result. My issue is that I need to call that result from the find_max function into the main function and from there, be able to print it. I'm not worried about the syntax for printing it, my issue is that with calling the result of the function into the main function.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my changes to the main function.

Comment: Ah, as I said, try moving the call for `find_max` after your `print_array` call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when declaring the array this way:

```
int data[DATA_SIZE] = {0};
```

so all 20 elements in it equals zero.
your main function should look like this:

```
int main()
{
   // Declare array of integers
   const int DATA_SIZE = 20;
   int data[DATA_SIZE] = {0};

   // Initialize and print array
   init_array(data, DATA_SIZE, 100);
   cout<< find_max(data, DATA_SIZE)<< endl;
   print_array(data, DATA_SIZE);

   return 0 ;
}
```

you give the 20 elements random values first by calling init_array and then you try finding the Max of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your function the start address of your array and the size of array, then you can use pointers to traverse the array. :)